# Regex string transformation/extraction

Tags: regex, string

Code:

```
https://aaa.bbb.net/ccc/211099_589944494365122_1446403980_n.jpg
```

How can I get `589944494365122` out of that string using regex?

The best I can do so far is `_(.*)` resulting `589944494365122_1446403980_n.jpg`

Comment: is that url static? or do the surrounding values change?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should generalize your problem description, like that: How can I get the longest non-empty substring of digits after the first `_` in string? The regexp you literally asked for is `(589944494365122)`, but that's not what you expect.

According to my guess about what you want, the answer could be `_(\d+)`.

Comment: Description lacks the quality caused my language barrier and amount of experience with regex. Your answer did the job. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `\d+_(\d+)_\d+_n\.jpg`, but depending on the exact specification of the URL this may need a little bit of tweaking.

Also depending on the language, this may need to be altered a little bit. The solution I suggest will work for instance in Ruby (as well as many other regex implementations). Here `\d` matches any digit and `\d+` means one or more digits. I assume the letter before `.jpg` is always `n` but you may change this by either replacing `n` with `.`(any character) or with `\w` (any word character).

Comment: To avoid confusion, I find it's best to show regexes in their "canonical" form.  In other words, don't double up the backslashes unless you're presenting the regex in the form of (for example) a Java string literal, like `"\\d+"`.

Comment: I used to write regexes like so,but too often I got the question `but your regex is not working on language X` and it turns out that the reason is that the backlash is not escaped. So to save one more answer I now add the 'escaped' version.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of extraction I can see in your input is:

```
211099_589944494365122_1446403980
[0-9]+_ part we want  _[0-9]+
```

so a regex with look-behind and look-ahead will help:

```
'(?<=\d_)\d+(?=_\d)'
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo " https://aaa.bbb.net/ccc/211099_589944494365122_1446403980_n.jpg"|grep -Po '(?<=\d_)\d+(?=_\d)'
589944494365122
```

Answer (score 1):

This works;

```
var s = "https://aaa.bbb.net/ccc/211099_589944494365122_1446403980_n.jpg";
var m = /_([^_]*)/.exec(s);
console.log( m[1] ); // 589944494365122
```